# .NET Generics Question

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Can someone please explain why I am getting a compile error asking for an explicit cast? Since I'm constraining the output, I thought this would be allowed without any brute force.

** THANK YOU EVERYONE. IT WAS CONFUSING THE WAY I PRESENTED THE QUESTION. **

```
public interface IQuery<TInput, TOutput>
{
    TOutput Execute(TInput input);
}

public abstract class PagedQuery<TInput, TOutput> : IQuery<TInput, TOutput>
    where TOutput : IEnumerable<TOutput>
{
    public TOutput Execute(TInput input)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<TOutput>(); // error here..
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, you're saying `TOutput` must be an `IEnumerable` of itself? That sounds strange.

Comment: It looks to me like you're returning an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TOutput>>. Is that what's you're intending?

Comment: the IQuery interface is generic in the sense it does not always return sequences. for the paged query, it ALWAYS does, so that is why I added the constraint. does that help?

Comment: @Sven: Isn't that the curiously recurring template pattern in C++?

Comment: I don't think the constraint makes sense. Whatever TOutput is, the constraint always wants it to be an IEnumerable of that type, so of TOutput is IEnumerable<foo> then the constraint says it has to be IEnumerable<IEnumerable<foo>>

Comment: Replace `IEnumerable<TOutput>` with `object` and then you should see where's your problem.

Comment: I have some query handlers that return objects and some that return collections of objects. when deriving from PagedQuery, it has to always be a collection. does that help?

Comment: @Mehrdad: yes, which makes sense for something like `IEquatable<T>`. I don't think I've ever seen it used on `IEnumerable<T>`, and especially not as a constraint.

Comment: Marco - can you simply always return a collection of objects, with just one member in the collection when there's only a single result?

Comment: Also, to support co/contravariance correctly, update your interface definition as `public interface IQuery<in TInput, out TOutput>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Enumerable.Empty<TOutput>()` returns *an implementation* of `IEnumerable<TOutput>`. Just because `TOutput` *also* implements `IEnumerable<TOutput>` doesn't mean that you can convert *any* `IEnumerable<TOutput>` value to `TOutput`.

I agree with the commentators who say that constraining `TOutput` to return a sequence of itself is pretty odd, by the way.

I suspect you actually want something like this:

```
public abstract class PagedQuery<TInput, TElement>
    : IQuery<TInput, IEnumerable<TElement>>
{
    public IEnumerable<TElement> Execute(TInput input)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<TElement>();
    }
}
```

That makes a lot more sense to me.

EDIT: I've renamed the type parameter to make it clearer. So for `IQuery<,>`, `TOutput=IEnumerable<TElement>` - so a `PagedQuery` returns a sequence of elements, not a sequence of *pages*, each of which itself is a sequence of pages, each of which itself is a sequence of pages ad infinitum.

Comment: odd even though the class is called PagedQuery? you cannot page through non-lists.

Comment: @Marco: Sure, but you wouldn't want each element of the PagedQuery to be another page, would you? It just returns a page. See my edit for the suggested solution.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is expecting you to return `TOutput` instead of an `IEnumerable<TOutput>`, it doesn't matter that your constraint specifies that `TOutput` inherits from `IEnumerable<TOutput>`, as the types aren't the same.

If you can, changing the type in the interface and abstract class on the `Execute` method to `IEnumerable<TOutput>` solves the compiler issue.

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving TOutput to be the payload of the IEnumerable you're returning:

```
    public interface IQuery<TInput, TOutput>
    {
        IEnumerable<TOutput> Execute(TInput input);
    }

    public abstract class PagedQuery<TInput, TOutput> : IQuery<TInput, TOutput>
    {
        public IEnumerable<TOutput> Execute(TInput input)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<TOutput>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you try to do is create a generic class `PagedQuery` where the output is always enumerable, while the generic `IQuery` interface doesn't necessarily produce enumerable ouput.

I guess you could write this to accomplish that:

```
// Define other methods and classes here
public interface IQuery<TInput, TOutput>
{
    TOutput Execute(TInput input);
}

public class PagedQuery<TInput, TOutput> : IQuery<TInput, IEnumerable<TOutput>>
{
    public IEnumerable<TOutput> Execute(TInput input)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<TOutput>();
    }
}
```

Now you can write

```
var query = new PagedQuery<int, int>();
IEnumerable<int> output = query.Execute(0);
```